# Empty accessors do matter? Regarding value types and their modification

Tags: c#, types, accessor

I have following code that does not work due to "a" being a value typed. But I thought it would not work even without accessors, but it did:

```
class Program
    {
        a _a  //with accessors it WONT compile
        {
            get; 
            set;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p._a.X = 5; //when both accessors are deleted, compiler does not
                        //complain about _a.X not being as variable
        }
    }
    struct a
    {
       public int X;
    }
```

It does not work as "a" is struct. But when I delete accessors from "_a" instance, it works. I do not understand why.
Thanks

Comment: You cannot delete accessors. You have merely replaced the custom accessors by a default implementation.

Comment: I can get  a _a; easily. And then it compiles.

Comment: Some tips: 1) use better names. 2) use class instead of struct. 3) if you use a struct, design it as immutable.

Comment: Henk, thank you but its all only for question. I was curious why accessors, even when empty, do matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main feature of value types is that they are copied rather than being passed by reference.

When you have a value type, and an accessor, you essentially have a value type being returned from a method, which causes a copy (the following two examples are the same):

```
ValueType Property { get { return x; } } // Will make a copy of x
ValueType Method() { return x; }    // Will make a copy of x
```

If you now assign to the returned value, you're assigning to a *copy* of x. So any changes made to the value returned from the property will be immediately lost.

When you remove the { get; } accessor, you've now got a basic field, e.g.:

```
int field;
```

or

```
ValueType field;
```

Which means no copy is made, which means when assigning to the field, you're no longer assigning to a copy.

Comment: The first line is wrong. The rest of the answer is OK. Main difference between value/reference types is what happens when copying them. Not stack/heap.

Comment: Ok, but I have read that get; and set; are implemented by default. But if it was true, it would not compile.

Comment: @Henk: I knew someone would pick me up on that ;) Truth is they *are* allocated on the stack though! Changed.

Comment: @petr. No, get and set aren't implemented by default. If you remove the accessors, you have a basic field. Think about it, how else do you declare a field?

Comment: @Groky: they *typically* are but not always. Reference types may also go on the stack if the runtime decides it's better (and doesn't affect the logic). But you have my +1 vote!

Comment: @Groky: not always. Value types can be fields inside reference types. And in the end, it does not matter.

Comment: @petr: you can omit set _or_ get to create a read-only or a write-only property. You can't omit both.

Comment: @Petr: And if you omit both, you make it no longer a property, but a field.

Comment: @Petr: leaving out the `{ }` is what makes it a field. You cannot have an empty `{ }` here.

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete both accessors.

This way:

```
a _a;
```

it works, but it's not a property any more.

---

Edit: With a property, the value you get from p._a is a result of a function call. If you even modify it, the modified value will by no means "written back" to the "original" `_a`. Instead, you will just modify a temporary, returned by the getter-function.

C# could allow this, but it would lead to confusion, since people would expect that after `p._a.X = 5; int xx = p._a.X;` the value of `xx` would be 5. But it won't be so. Because p_.a is indeed not a variable :-)

---

The difference is that with

```
a _a;
```

your `_a` is a field; in case of

```
a _a { get; set; }
```

`_a` is a property. And the case

```
a _a { }
```

is not allowed.

Comment: Yes, but when deleted, I can modify the struct this way:p._a.X=5 and it does not says "X is not variable" any more.

Comment: Indeed. With a property, p._a is a function call, it returns a value which cannot be modified. You can assign it to a variable and modify:
`a new_a = p._a; new_a.X = 5;`

Comment: The story is that you cannot modify the "value" of `_a`, because there is no value at all. As it's a property, it is returned by a function, so any changes you are making to it won't be noticed by the class `Program` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `p._a.X = 5;` won't work is because `p._a` returns a value of the type `a`. Values cannot change. But if you put the value in a variable, you may change the value of the variable.